# Run one command for certain duration, exit, run next

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that runs ngrok first with my token and then with my desired subdomain like this

```
"C:\ngrok\ngrok.exe" -authtoken mytoken 8080
"C:\ngrok\ngrok.exe" -subdomain=example 8080
```

Now currently I when I run, I have to exit from 1st line by ctrl+c so it moves to next line. Is there a way say after n-seconds it happens automatically?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what it sounds like is happening is that the batch file executes the ngrok.exe file and then waits for the ngrok.exe process to terminate before moving on.  Now I can only speculate without knowing more, but that would be my guess.  To get around this the solution is actually rather simple.  You just need to start the ngrok.exe file under a new taskname:

```
cd C:\ngrok
start "ngrok" "ngrok.exe" -authtoken mytoken 8080
timeout 5
taskkill /f /im ngrok.exe
start "ngrok" "ngrok.exe" -subdomain=example 8080
```

and if you wanted to run the program all within one program window you could use the "start /b" command.  More information can be found here:
http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

Comment: Hey Mike thanks for your response,  I ran your code and it says windows can not find authtoken and waits and then says can't find subdomain. I just want the first line to execute for some time and then Quit and go to second line

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out in the right direction, Please correct your answer, after start you need to put the title of the window which is required which in this case it assumes to be "C:\ngrok\ngrok.exe" and messes everything up, Thanks

Comment: Technically, a title is only required if you have any quotes in the start string. In this case, you could also leave the quotes out altogether and it would still work.

Comment: I achieved my objective by using the above but using /MIN in the first line and using TSKILL ngrok after timeout, Thanks

Comment: I downloaded ngrok.exe to test and it worked for me when I took out the quotations.  But I believe it would be wiser to go with the taskkill option now knowing what the program does, therefor i have edited it to reflect that update.